# How to store usrename and make it accessible everywhere?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a text field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user">
```

and I have a button that will redirect to another page. On that page, I want to print the username typed in by the user. How can I do that?

My preference is ionic.

Comment: What routing are you using?

Comment: I preferred using token based authentication, upon login store user details together with the token, in succeeding authentication provider should check if token is valid and allow system to access user details stored in tokens, this is secured in this way.

Answer (score 4):

`ionic` works on top of `angular`. There are various ways by which you can achieve this functionality:

**1) Use constants file to keep your value**
   Create a file called constants.js, include it in your index.html as:

```
<script src="Constants/Constants.js"></script>
```

declare key value pair combinations in it as:

```
var url_config = {
      "USER_NAME" : "LOGIN_USER",
    };
```

in your controller file, set the `USER_NAME` value as:

```
url_config.USER_NAME = $scope.user; //the model variable name that you had used
```

Use this value, where you want to access as:

```
$scope.loggedInUser = url_config.USER_NAME; // you will get the value here
```

The disadvantage here is that the value will get lost if you reload the screen. This can be ignored in android or ios app that you create using `phonegap`, the screens can't be refreshed, but if you are using web app this won't be a recommendable method.

**2) Use a service to pass the constants**
     Create a utility service to keep the variable

```
angular.module('myApp').service('UtilityService', function () {                
    this.USER_NAME  = '';
});
```

You can set this in your controller as:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, UtilityService) {
     UtilityService.USER_NAME   = $scope.user;
});
```

Access it in your other controller as:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('UserController', function ($scope, UtilityService) {
         $scope.loggedInUser = UtilityService.user;
    });
```

This is a reliable way and a recommended method too.

**3) Use local Storage**
Here you can use the `HTML5` feature of local storage to access the value from the browser's local storage.

Set the value in the login controller as:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $localStorage) {
         $localStorage.USER_NAME = $scope.loggedInUser;
    });
```

In the receiving controller use it as:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('UserController', function ($scope, $localStorage) {
         $scope.loggedInUser = $localStorage.USER_NAME;
    });
```

This will pertain the value even if the app goes to background or quits. Unless you clear the app cache or app data manually, the value will be saved.

For accessing `$localStorage`, you will require to use the `ngStorage` plugin that you can access from [github](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) and follow the instructions for instalation, then inject `ngStorage` as:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngStorage']);
```

Now you are ready to use the `$localStorage`, provided you have included it in the controller where you are willing to access it.

4) **Use session storage**
Using the same `ngStorage` plugin you can use the session storage via `$sessionStorage`.

Set the value in the login controller as:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $sessionStorage) {
         $sessionStorage.USER_NAME = $scope.loggedInUser;
    });
```

In the receiving controller use it as:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('UserController', function ($scope, $sessionStorage) {
         $scope.loggedInUser = $sessionStorage.USER_NAME;
    });
```

Session storage keeps the data in session which gets expired after a limited time. This usage would be recommended for features like access tokens etc. For this scenario of username this won't be a recommended method

Answer (score 2):

There are mainly two ways to achieve this:

**1.By using Constants**

**app.js**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
    .constant('appConstant', {
        user: ''
    })
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('ionicApp.home', ['ionic'])
    .controller('homeCtrl', ['$state', 'appConstant', function($state, appConstant) {
        'use strict';
        $scope.user = '';
        $scope.onClick = function() {

            appConstant.user = $scope.user;
        };
    }]);
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user">
<button ng-click="onClick()">Submit</button>
```

Now you will get user name from any controllers by using `appConstant.user`

**2.By using localstorage**

**Controller**

```
angular.module('ionicApp.home', ['ionic'])
    .controller('homeCtrl', ['$state', '$localStorage', function($state, $localStorage) {
        'use strict';
        $scope.user='';
        $scope.onClick = function() {
          $localStorage.set('user', user);
        };
    }]);
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user">
<button ng-click="onClick()">Submit</button>
```

Now you will get user name from any controllers by using `$localStorage.get('user')`